# Мультиэкранная система

Tags: windows

Необходимо установить мультиэкранную систему под Windows 8.1 32-ух битка. Хотел уточнить тонкости реализации. Какие переходники или разветвители использовать, чтобы свести все мониторы к одной системе? Какие дистрибутивы использовать чтобы синхронизировать мониторы? Есть ли такая реализация, чтобы курсор свободно переходил с экрана на экран, и при этом было разделение программное разделение(например: Я на одном экране открыл Google Chrome, а на другом запустил Консоль, и система блокировала возможность перетянуть окна с одного монитора на другой)?

Comment: В 8.1 это из коробки. Лишь бы было нужное вам кол-во видеовыходов. __и система блокировала возможность перетянуть окна с одного монитора на другой__ такого нет

Comment: Насчет мониторов  - используйте ПО виртуальных рабочих столов.